# geo_ip kibana index and logstash filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, elk

I created a logstash server with this filter

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.7/logstash-config-for-filebeat-modules.html#parsing-apache2

but my problem is that the kibana map does not show anything.
 that's what I have in my kibana index patterns

> [image]

do you have any idea what i missed. Thank you

Comment: `apache.access.geoip.ip` as a `string` is not good (it should be `ip` instead). Can you add your index mapping to your question?

Comment: is there any way to change the index? how can I get the index mapping?

Comment: Go inside Dev Tools and type `GET your-index-name/_mapping`

Comment: Did you run the [`setup` command in your Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-template.html) to setup the index?

Comment: do you need a specific  attribute, because there is a lot:

Comment: Just the `apache.access.geoip.ip` one, I'm pretty sure it's of type "text"... Also can you answer my previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @Val
I executed these 3 commands and it work :

```
sudo filebeat setup --template -E output.logstash.enabled=false -E 'output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]'

Output
Loaded index template
```

and

```
sudo filebeat setup -e -E output.logstash.enabled=false -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=['localhost:9200'] -E setup.kibana.host=localhost:5601

sudo systemctl restart filebeat
```